# Position:Absolute in a TD different for IE and Chrome

Tags: css

Basically, in a TD, I have some writing "Viewing Orders" in a span.  Before that span, I have an image in a span and after that span I have another image in a span.  So 3 spans lined up in a row, inside a td:

```
<span id=\"test_float\"><img src=\"green_check.png\">&nbsp=&nbspCompleted</span><span id=\"test_float_3\" class=\"font24\">Viewing ".$user_first_name."'s Orders</span><span id=\"test_float_2\"><img src=\"green_edit_pencil_small.jpg\">&nbsp=&nbspEdit</span>
```

CSS:

```
#test_float {
position: absolute;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 15px;
}
#test_float_2 {
position: absolute;
margin-left: 90px;
margin-top: 15px;
}
#test_float_3 {
position: relative;
}
```

In IE it looks great.  In chrome it doesn't work.  I've narrowed it down to POSITION:ABSOLUTE.  In IE it puts the first span "test_float" in the top left corner of the TD.  In Chrome it puts it in the top left corner of the middle span "test_float_3" of the td (so it sits on top of the word "viewing")

In chrome, if I remove "positon:absolute" it goes where it does in IE with the "position:absolute" code, but then it pushes the middle span over a little and makes it look like crap.

Now, I know I can fix this with making the 1 TD into 3 TD's and having each span in their own TD but i was hoping there was a fix for this "position:absolute" difference in IE and Chrome so I can learn why its happening.

usually things work in chrome and not IE, its weird that its backwards with this one thing.  the span on the right does the same thing for both browsers, goes to the top left corner AFTER the middle span and adjusts properly with the css code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ It maybe that your browser is doing some tricks as you cant expect to all work the same. you need to reset the CSS before working with CSS ideally.

Answer (score 0):

My solution ended up being to change the section labeled "test_float" from a span to a div and then it would act the same on the browsers and then i could position it as needed.